# Is it possible to create one storage for login token instead of multiple storages?

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins, exceljs

We've developed **Excel JS add-in on React.**
Now we started with login functionality and faced with a following problem.

Currently **our custom login** token should be saved in 3 workspaces (ribbon, task pane and custom functions).

Is it possible to implement the **single** storage source for custom login token? Because currently it is implemented in the opposite way. All three workspaces have its own storages and they are not synchronized among each other.

Note, the variant with usage of the Office Runtime Storage is not working for us, because of user’s data security.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same storage for the ribbon, task pane, and custom functions by configuring your Excel add-in to run in a shared runtime environment (currently in preview).  Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-shared-overview.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a quick response!
Just to be aware of all possible variants, do we have other options, except the Shared runtime environment?

Comment: Other than OfficeRuntime.Storage, no. This is one of the key scenarios that the shared runtime environment aims to make easier.